# Switch statement with onclick not working

Tags: javascript, onclick, switch-statement

I want:
When users click one of the colors(red/yellow/green), the sentence below changes differently.
(by using switch statement and onclick with arguments)

What I tried:
Assigned onclick and ids to each color on html and wrote switch statement on js.
But nothing reacts to the cases of the switch and default is processed.

```js
var elem1 = document.getElementById("action");
var elem2 = document.getElementById("light");
var red = document.getElementById("red");
var yellow = document.getElementById("yellow");
var green = document.getElementById("green");

var decision = judge;  

function judge(red, yellow, green){

  switch(decision){    
    
    case red:
        elem1.innerHTML = "stop";
        elem2.innerHTML = "red";
        break;
    case yellow:
        elem1.innerHTML = "go with causion";
        elem2.innerHTML = "yellow";
        break;
    case green:
        elem1.innerHTML = "go";
        elem2.innerHTML = "green";
        break;
    default:
        console.log("error");
        break;
  }
}
```

```html
<p>◆Traffic Light◆</p>
  
<p onclick="judge(red)" id="red"><font color="red">RED</font></p>
<p onclick="judge(yellow)" id="yellow"><font color="yellow">YELLOW</font></p>
<p onclick="judge(green)" id="green"><font color="lightgreen">GREEN</font></p>
  
<p>"I'll<span id="action">___</span>because the traffic light is<span id="light">___</span>!"</p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Use `this.id` while passing id as an argument.
- No need to have variables with color names
- In this snippet, the `case` should be as `string`

```js
var elem1 = document.getElementById("action");
var elem2 = document.getElementById("light");

function judge(decision) {
  switch (decision) {
    case "red":
      elem1.innerHTML = "stop";
      elem2.innerHTML = "red";
      break;
    case "yellow":
      elem1.innerHTML = "go with causion";
      elem2.innerHTML = "yellow";
      break;
    case "green":
      elem1.innerHTML = "go";
      elem2.innerHTML = "green";
      break;
    default:
      console.log("error");
      break;
  }
}
```

```html
<p>◆Traffic Light◆</p>
<p onclick="judge(this.id)" id="red">
  <font color="red">RED</font>
</p>
<p onclick="judge(this.id)" id="yellow">
  <font color="yellow">YELLOW</font>
</p>
<p onclick="judge(this.id)" id="green">
  <font color="lightgreen">GREEN</font>
</p>
<p>"I'll <span id="action">___</span> because the traffic light is <span id="light">___</span>!"</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please change method definition and argument list as below.

```
var elem1 = document.getElementById("action");
var elem2 = document.getElementById("light");
var red = document.getElementById("red");
var yellow = document.getElementById("yellow");
var green = document.getElementById("green");



function judge(color){
  var decision = color;
   case red:
        elem1.innerHTML = " stop ";
        elem2.innerHTML = " red ";
        break;
    case yellow:
        elem1.innerHTML = " go with causion ";
        elem2.innerHTML = " yellow ";
        break;
    case green:
        elem1.innerHTML = " go ";
        elem2.innerHTML = " green ";
        break;
    default:
        console.log("error");
        break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

document.getElementById("red") will not provide color red it will give you element

```js
var elem1 = document.getElementById("action");
var elem2 = document.getElementById("light");

function judge(decision){
  switch(decision) {
    case 'red':
        elem1.innerHTML = "stop";
        elem2.innerHTML = "red";
        break;
    case 'yellow':
        elem1.innerHTML = "go with causion";
        elem2.innerHTML = "yellow";
        break;
    case 'green':
        elem1.innerHTML = "go";
        elem2.innerHTML = "green";
        break;
    default:
        console.log("error");
        break;
  }
}
```

```html
<p>◆Traffic Light◆</p>
  
<p onclick="judge('red')" id="red"><font color="red">RED</font></p>
<p onclick="judge('yellow')" id="yellow"><font color="yellow">YELLOW</font></p>
<p onclick="judge('green')" id="green"><font color="lightgreen">GREEN</font></p>
  
<p>"I'll <span id="action">___</span> because the traffic light is <span id="light">___</span> !"</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

you had a few mistakes in the JS code, i fixed them for you in the code below. You should've passed the `judge()` parameter "decision" into the switch statement.

You can use `this.id` to pass the current id into the function

I did a bit of formatting in the html to make the output more appealing for the user.

## html

```html
<p>◆Traffic Light◆</p>
  
<p onclick="judge(this.id)" id="red"><font color="red">RED</font></p>
<p onclick="judge(this.id)" id="yellow"><font color="yellow">YELLOW</font></p>
<p onclick="judge(this.id)" id="green"><font color="lightgreen">GREEN</font></p>
  
<p>"I'll <span id="action">___</span> because the traffic light is <span id="light">___</span>!"</p>
```

## JS

```js
var elem1 = document.getElementById("action");
var elem2 = document.getElementById("light");
var red = document.getElementById("red");
var yellow = document.getElementById("yellow");
var green = document.getElementById("green");

var decision = judge;  

function judge(decision){

  switch(decision){    
    
    case "red":
        elem1.innerHTML = "stop";
        elem2.innerHTML = "red";
        break;
    case "yellow":
        elem1.innerHTML = "go with causion";
        elem2.innerHTML = "yellow";
        break;
    case "green":
        elem1.innerHTML = "go";
        elem2.innerHTML = "green";
        break;
    default:
        console.log("error");
        break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To improve upon your system it would be suggested to used an A / Link instead of a P for your click items as this will help all browsers and users understand this is a "clickable" item and will by the nature of a A/Href item provide additional visual clues, finger mouse pointer and other highlights and visual aids for users to understand the user can click on the item.

While not absolutely necessary I also recommend wrapping internal case items with { } but that may be more of a personal preference/style.

```
<p>◆Traffic Light◆</p>

    <p><a href="javascript:judge(red);" id="red"><font color="red">RED</font></a></p>
    <p><a href="javascript:judge(yellow);" id="yellow"><font color="yellow">YELLOW</font></a></p>
    <p><a href="javascript:judge(green);" id="green"><font color="lightgreen">GREEN</font></a></p>

    <p>"I'll<span id="action">___</span>because the traffic light is<span id="light">___</span>!"</p>

<script>
       var elem1 = document.getElementById("action");
        var elem2 = document.getElementById("light");
        var red = document.getElementById("red");
        var yellow = document.getElementById("yellow");
        var green = document.getElementById("green");

        function judge(color){
            switch(color)
            {
                case red: 
                {
                    elem1.innerHTML = " stop ";
                    elem2.innerHTML = " red ";
                    break;
                }
                case yellow:
                {
                    elem1.innerHTML = " go with causion ";
                    elem2.innerHTML = " yellow ";
                    break;
                }
                case green:
                {
                    elem1.innerHTML = " go ";
                    elem2.innerHTML = " green ";
                    break;
                }
                default:
                {
                    console.log("error");
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
</script>
```